# How to dump llvm::instruction while debugging

Tags: gdb, llvm, llvm-ir

I would like to ask if it is possible to dump out the text format of certain instruction while debugging(I'm using gdb in vscode)??

I tried `I->dump()` and `I->print(errs())` but not work....

Thus I would lie to ask if it is possible to do so??

Answer (score 1):

Given an `llvm::Instruction *I`, the way to print it is indeed `I->dump()`. But you need to have some form of `stderr` hooked up to see the output. If you have the terminal output from `gdb` visible, you should be able to see the textual form.

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm using vscode with gdb to debug it. It actually crashed when I type `I->dump` in the watch tag......it reported an error of `/usr/bin/opt: symbol lookup error: ./build/lib/libDFG.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm5Value4dumpEv`